# user input that uses 'while' loop python

Tags: python

I'm currently making a game with a scoreboard that requires the user's name.
If I were to make a programme that asks for the user's name, and if it is >20 chars, it would loop back and ask again

```
name_list = []

name = input('Please enter your name (not more than 20 chars): ')

while len(name) > 20:
    name = input('Please enter your name (not more than 20 chars): ')

if len(name) <= 20:
    name_list.append(name)
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this

Comment: You don't need the `if` at the end. It only gets out of the loop if that condition is true.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we fix non-working code. Code reviews of working code can be requested at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But usually the reviewed code is more complex that this.